# Adding Bitmaps into an Array, then set it in ImageView inside GridView

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, bitmap, imageview

Since I was getting out of memory error when a picture taken with the phones camera was added into the imageView inside GridView, I tried to rescale it - as a bitmap (This worked just fine). I now want to add the images into an Array from which the items are going to load in the GridViews ImageView.

What I tried :

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public Uri imageUri;
public String picture;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


private Context mContext;

public ImageGridAdapter(Context c) {

    this.mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
        return bitmapArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    try {
        imageUri = PictureGroupActivity.selectedImage;
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

        picture = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}


    bitmapArrayList.add(BitmapScaled(picture, 100, 100));
    Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "bitmapArrayList je: " + bitmapArrayList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    }  else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArrayList.get(position));

    return imageView;
}

private Bitmap BitmapScaled(String picturePath, int width, int height) {
    BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

}
}
```

Setting the adapter to GridView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_group_activity_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.picture_group_gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageGridAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(PictureGroupActivity.this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Choosing the Image:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String picturePath = loadPath();

    if (id == R.id.addPictureFolder) {
        if (picturePath != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Click the plus button to add pictures", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    } else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.picture_group_gridView);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        selectedImage = data.getData();

        Intent restart = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(restart);

    }
}
```

This does like nothing, no error, no Image is displayed, nothing.

What am I doing wrong? (If I'm not anywhere near the answer, how do you do it?)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code where you are setting adapter to gridview?

Comment: Done, edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting arraylist in adapter from activity. bitmapArrayList size is zero thats why  gridview not showing anything. Please check the bitmapArrayList size.

Comment: Are you saying I have to set the ArrayList inside the activity?.. Or else Im not really sure what exactly do you mean.

Comment: From where adapter getting that arraylist?

Comment: general process
myAdapter = new ChatlistAdapter(onePerUSerItems, context);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: I think you are not arraylist to adapter or arraylist size is zero in the adapter.

Comment: Let me know I can help you

Comment: What I tried to do, was, since Im rescaling it in the adapter, add the rescaled image into an ArrayList and then add those items/images into the gridView's imageView. Another way I thought I would try is rescaling the image in the activity as well as adding it in the arrayList in the activity. Then take the arrayList to the adapter and set it in the imageView. Would that work?

Comment: Gonna ty later today, I'll let you know :D Also thank you for the response ^^